# Error in sort.list(y) for a stacked species distribution model

Tags: r, dataframe, models, bioinformatics

I am currently trying to run a stacked species distribution model through a high performance cluster using the package "SSDM". I am currently using the 'stack_modelling' function. My code is as follows:

```
      Env <- load_var(path = getwd(), files = NULL, format = c(".grd", ".tif", ".asc",
                                                     ".sdat", ".rst", ".nc", ".envi", ".bil", ".img"), categorical = "af_anthrome.asc",
            Norm = TRUE, tmp = TRUE, verbose = TRUE, GUI = FALSE)

    Occurrences <- load_occ(path = getwd(), Env, file = "Final_African_bird_occurrence_rarefied_points.csv", 
                    Xcol = "decimallong", Ycol = "decimallat", Spcol = "species", GeoRes = FALSE,
                    sep = ",", verbose = TRUE, GUI = FALSE)

    stack <- stack_modelling(c("GLM", "GAM", "MARS", "GBM", "RF", "CTA", "MAXENT", "ANN", "SVM"), Occurrences, Env, Xcol = "Xcol",
            Ycol = "Xcol", Pcol = NULL, Spcol = "Spcol", rep = 1,
            name = "Stack", save = TRUE, path = getwd(), PA = NULL,
            cv = "holdout", cv.param = c(0.75, 1), thresh = 1001,
            axes.metric = "Pearson", uncertainty = TRUE, tmp = TRUE,
            ensemble.metric = c("AUC"), ensemble.thresh = c(0.75), weight = TRUE,
            method = "bSSDM", metric = "TSS", rep.B = 1000, range = NULL,
            endemism = NULL, verbose = TRUE, GUI = FALSE, cores = 500)
```

However soon after submitting my job I received this error message:

```
    Occurrences loading 
    Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
    Have you called 'sort' on a list?
    Calls: load_occ -> as.factor -> as.factor -> factor -> sort.list
    Execution halted
```

I have tried running this analyses using a small subset of my data and i do get the code to run to the #Ensemble Models Creation# stage however i then receive the same message.

Is this to do with my occurrences file? My occurrences are read and recognised by R and when I convert the file to a data frame using the 'as.data.frame' command still the same error message.

Thanks for your kind help,
Nikhail

Comment: What you read "Final_African_bird_occurrence_rarefied_points.csv" into a data.frame, what is the class of decimallat column: `class(df$decimallat)`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Vince. There was an extremely strange error in the .csv file which I have since corrected. This error only showed up once I viewed the dataset in a text editor. Thank your for your input however, I will remember this if I encounter further problems